# Winforms: изменение свойств компонента Chart

Tags: c#, winforms, диаграммы

В процессе создания приложения обнаружил баг, не пойму в чём заключается ошибка.

В общем, есть блок кода.

```
ca = Graph.ChartAreas[0];
ca.CursorX.IsUserEnabled = true;
ca.CursorX.IsUserSelectionEnabled = true;
ca.CursorY.IsUserEnabled = true;
ca.CursorY.IsUserSelectionEnabled = true;
ca.AxisX.Title = "Секунды";
ca.AxisY.Title = "Температура";
Graph.Series[ListGraph.SelectedIndex].Points.AddXY(x, pars.DATAIllum);
Graph.Series[ListGraph.SelectedIndex + 7].Points.AddXY(x, 750);
Graph.Series[ListGraph.SelectedIndex + 14].Points.AddXY(x, 200);
ca.AxisY.ScaleView.Zoomable = true;
ca.CursorY.AutoScroll = true;
ca.AxisY.ScrollBar.ButtonStyle = ScrollBarButtonStyles.SmallScroll;
ca.AxisY.ScaleView.SmallScrollSize = 100;
ca.AxisY.ScaleView.Zoom(pars.DATAIllum - 95, pars.DATAIllum + 5);
ca.AxisX.ScaleView.Zoom(0, 100);
ca.AxisY.Interval = 5;
ca.AxisX.Interval = 10;
ca.AxisX.Minimum = 0;
ca.AxisX.Maximum = 100;
ca.AxisY.Maximum = pars.DATAIllum + 5;
ca.RecalculateAxesScale();
x += 10;
```

Есть `switch`, который из `ComboBox` получает индекс выбранного элемента и к нему применяет этот код, меняется в нём только подпись оси и переменные, хранящие данные.

Суть проблемы такова. Если переключить в `ComboBox` элемент, но при этом ничего не добавить на график, то если переключить на другой элемент, то свойства для `Axis`, а также `Zoom` применяются только на 3 итерацию кода, хотя проходится по всем командам, в чём может быть загвоздка?

Comment: Попробуйте контролу графика делать .Invalidate();

Comment: Не помогло. Ещё кое-что уточню, что заметил только сейчас. При первой итерации добавления точки на график всё в норме, видимая область от 0 до 100 по абсциссам и по ординатам, соответственно, тоже всё нормально, но как происходит вторая итерация, то у меня рисуется в нужных точках, а вот зум становится от -9 до 101, причём так на любом графике, вне зависимости от данных. Вот и понять не могу -откуда оно тут взялось? На 3-ю итерацию всё нормально и дальше,также, всё нормально

Comment: нужно больше кода, что за итерации? где-то цикл? покажите его.

Comment: Показывать смысла нет. Это компонент Timer. Добавление у меня происходит просто по событию "тика". То, что это событие делает, как раз, в кусочке кода выше

Comment: В дотнете несколько родных таймеров (и может быть множество сторонних). Какой именно используется?

Comment: `Invalidate` куда вставляли? В показанный код или в событие изменения значения комбобокса?

Comment: Использовался родной Timer в панели элементов

Comment: Не знаю как конкретно человеку здесь ответить, но `Invalidate` и туда, и туда пробовал,результат один и тот же

Comment: То есть `System.Windows.Forms.Timer`. Указывайте пространство имён, тогда станет понятно, что это за класс. А в случае стороннего компонента, нужно указать и библиотеку.

Comment: Чтобы обратиться к конкретному человеку, напишите значок `@` перед его именем.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov да, именно это пространство имён.